# Can a HTML form be used offline?

Tags: html, css, kindle

I'm wanting to create a HTML page to be accessed via the kindle browser. I'm wanting to create a puzzle using a form and, when the user solves the puzzle, it will just create a new puzzle. I'm aiming to use cookies to hold the users progress. It can cope with HTML and CSS 3. Can I get a normal web page to redraw itself after the user submits without going back to the server?

Before I get started on the project I just wanted to see whether it was possible doing it this way. Ideally I'd like to put the HTML, CSS and any data into a mobi format but I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask that.

Anyway, thanks for reading.

Mike

Comment: only possible if you can use Javascript.

Comment: Any code that's already in the browser can continue to run offline, yes.  A connection is only needed when the client tries to fetch data from the server.

Comment: you should read about PWA https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/offline-quickstart

Comment: @cloned : I believe the kindle browser can deal with Javascript.

Comment: @David : I'm fine with that, I don't need anything from the server. I just need a html page to generate a puzzle (using javascript) and, when the user has finished the puzzle, create another. If I can avoid going to a server brilliant. If I can just use a locally stored html page great. If I can use a html page that's been embedded into a downloaded mobi file then brilliant :)

Comment: @cloned : I'm fairly sure the kindle browser wouldn't support PWA.